# Would it be wrong if I picked a model with less accuracy in this case?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, accuracy

I have some data containing a list of 2000 questions, some features such as length of question or time needed to solve it, and a score between 0 and 1. The closer to one, the more people solve it correctly compared to the ones who got it wrong. So I created 3 classes: Easy, Medium, Hard.

First classification model:

```
Easy: >0.7
Medium: between 0.4 and 0.7
Hard: <0.4.
F1-value: 0,620
Accuracy: 71,9 % (92/128)
Rate true positives: 54,4 % (92/169)
Rate false positives: 0,107 (36/338)

True labels/Predicted labels        Easy      Hard     Medium
                            Easy    88%        -        12%   
                            Hard    55%        -        45%
                            Medium  75%        -        85%
```

There were barely any Hard questions so no wonder the model didn't work for them. So I tried to balance the number of values. For the second classification model:

```
Easy: >0.9
Medium: between 0.7 and 0.9
Hard: <0.7.
F1-value: 0,518
Accuracy: 60,6 % (86/142)
Rate true positives: 45,3 % (86/190)
Rate false positives: 0,147 (56/380)

True labels/Predicted labels        Easy      Hard       Medium
                            Easy    63%        19%        19%   
                            Hard    11%        58%        32%
                            Medium  20%        26%        54%
```

By all metrics the first model is better, but it's less balanced? What could I do to either find a better one or, if not, which one should I pick? Another idea is to create just two categories, Easy and Hard, but I would like to split in in three.

Comment: What are the values in the first three rows in the results? Do I understand correctly that those are two different models with test set results calculated on two different test sets?

Answer (score 1):

It seems more natural to do a regression. Any classification model is strongly influenced by the thresholds you choose.

One twist may help: most regression methods will work oddly since you have a minimum and a maximum value. So it might be better to transform the value using the inverse logistic function before making the regression.

Comment: I am trying this right now, but obviously I get zeroes and infinity values among the transformed values. Should I leave them like this?

Comment: No, I would choose a minimum and maximum value. Those zeroes are my mistake: I should have said "sigmoid" not "logistic".